# D3.js V3 for angular 2+, fill style typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to implement this [case](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799) on angular 6.

But in the implementation, I encountered a problem.In the setting `fill` style, there is a error in typescripe.

In `change(data)` function:

[image]

I tried to add the `<any>` tag and still can't solve it.

[image]

Angular error message:

```
: error TS2345: Argument of type '"fill"' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: string | number | boolean | ((datum: any, index: number, outerIndex: number) => ...'.
```

Vscode type error message:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(name: string, value: Primitive, priority?: string): Selection<any>', gave the following error. ....(omitted)
```

Comment: did you try `.style({ 'fill': function() { ... } })`

Comment: I tried it, although there was no error in angular, but the vscode still had errors and could not successfully draw the pie picture.

Comment: how about `(slice as any).enter().insert('path').style('fill', function () { ... })`

Comment: It's work, there are no error messages,thx.

Comment: I have posted this as answer so it may be helpful for anyone else with same problem. can you accept it?

Comment: I have accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how *typings* for D3 work but you can skip the error by treating the `slice` object as `any`:

```
(slice as any).enter().insert('path').style('fill', function () { .... })
          ^
----------^
```